# SQLite Datagrid Validation

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, combobox, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` on a WPF form that has the `ItemsSource` property set to a `DataTable`. This `DataTable` is populated from an SQLite table, and I'm displaying one of the columns by using a `DataGridTemplateColumn` that is filled with a `ComboBox`.  The `ComboBox` is correctly showing the `DisplayMember` (string) and `SelectedValue` (int) from class *DummyClass*.  However, when I select a value from the `ComboBox` the `DataGrid` is displaying a Validation error (red exclamation mark) next to the row.

I added an event handler for when the selection is changed for the `ComboBox` so that I could view the the validation error.  The validation error reads:

> Value '1' could not be converted.

where the '1' is whatever index was just selected in the `ComboBox`.

What is causing this validation error?

```
        InitializeComponent();

        DummyClassCollection = new ObservableCollection<DummyClass>();
        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { DisplayValue = "Item1", SelectedValue = 0 });
        DummyClassCollection.Add(new DummyClass() { DisplayValue = "Item2", SelectedValue = 1 });

        table = new DataTable();
        dgData.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;

        DataGridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory control = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ComboBox));

        control.SetValue(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, DummyClassCollection);
        control.SetValue(ComboBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, "DisplayValue");
        control.SetValue(ComboBox.SelectedValuePathProperty, "SelectedValue");

        control.AddHandler(ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent, new SelectionChangedEventHandler(ComboBox_SelectionChanged));

        Binding b = new Binding();
        b.Path = new PropertyPath("tableID");
        b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;

        control.SetBinding(ComboBox.SelectedValueProperty, b);

        dataTemplate.VisualTree = control;
        templateColumn.CellTemplate = dataTemplate;

        //dgData.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgData.Columns.Add(templateColumn);

        string connection = @"Data Source = " + database + "; Version=3; foreign keys=true;";
        sqlc = new SQLiteConnection(connection);
        sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM tblExample", sqlc);
        adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
        sqlcmdb = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);

        adapter.InsertCommand = sqlcmdb.GetInsertCommand();
        adapter.UpdateCommand = sqlcmdb.GetUpdateCommand();
        adapter.DeleteCommand = sqlcmdb.GetDeleteCommand();
        adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        templateColumn.Header = table.Columns[1].ColumnName;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just worked out a similar problem but in a Windows form DataGrid object.  I'm using SQLite tables as the data sources.  I had assigned a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with a DisplayMember and ValueMember from a specific SQLite table.  But the DataGrid did not display the DisplayMember value when I ran the code, all I could see was the integer value stored in the table bound to the DataGrid.

Turns out the SQLite datatype for the ValueMember table did not match the datatype of the field assigned to a combo box in the DataGrid. The ValueMember field in the lookup table was set to a SQLite data type 'Integer'.  The SQLite data type in the combo box field of the SQLite table bound to the DataGrid table is SQLite type 'int'.

SQLite type 'Integer' maps to .Net System.Int64 which in code is typeof(Long).

SQLite type 'int' maps to to .Net System.Int32 which in code is typeof(int).

So I modified the SQLite tables to be sure all integer type fields are SQLite type 'int'.

I then modified my C# DataSet code so that all integer type fields are set to typeof(int).

And now the DataGridViewComboBoxColumn is behaving as expected.

Comment: This is a much more detailed description of how you solved the essentially the same problem I ran into, so I'm marking this as the solution.  Hopefully you didn't bang your head against the wall as long as I did to end up discovering this seemingly trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

The column in the SQLite table is of type `Long` where my observable collection property was of type `int`.  This was causing the data validation error.